# How to zoom in and out an particular object with target set in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, program-entry-point, pinchzoom, gameobject

I created an 3dobject and set a game object as target, and added the below code to main camera. I am able to zoom into the 3d object, *but im not able to zoom out of it*. How to zoom out? i.e to go back to original position.

```
using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine;

public class zoo22 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movespeed = 35.0f;
    //you need to say how far from the object the camera will stop
    public float minimumDistanceFromTarget = 5f;
    public GameObject targetobject;
    private bool movingtowardstarget = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            if (movingtowardstarget == true)
            {
                movingtowardstarget = false;
            }
            else
            {
                movingtowardstarget = true;
            }
        }

        if (movingtowardstarget)
        {
            movetowardstarget(targetobject);
        }
    }

    public void movetowardstarget(GameObject target)
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) > minimumDistanceFromTarget) //we move only if we are further than the minimum distance
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, movespeed * Time.deltaTime);
        } else //otherwise, we stop moving
        {
            movingtowardstarget = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get your camera position before you start function movetoward, and use it when you want to go backward.

Answer (score 4):

I not got your movingtoward bool but you can handle your zoom easy.
First rotate your camera to look at your object and later apply zoom:

For example to zoom whith the mouse Wheel in a ortho camera you need to handle orthographicSize:

```
int orthographicSizeMin = 1;
int orthographicSizeMax = 6;

function Update()
{
     transform.LookAt(target);

     if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") &gt; 0) // forward
     {
         Camera.main.orthographicSize++;
     }
     if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") &lt; 0) // back
     {
         Camera.main.orthographicSize--;
     }
}
Camera.main.orthographicSize = Mathf.Clamp(Camera.main.orthographicSize, orthographicSizeMin, orthographicSizeMax );
```

For a perspective camera you need to handle field of view:

```
float minFov = 10f;
float maxFov = 90f;
float sensitivity = 10f;


function Update()
{
     transform.LookAt(target);
     float fov = Camera.main.fieldOfView;
     fov += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * sensitivity; 
     fov = Mathf.Clamp(fov, minFov, maxFov);
     Camera.main.fieldOfView = fov;
}
```

Comment: Camera.main.fieldOfView+=0.5f;

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same function to zoom in and zoom out. please check the example below. Enter negative velocity to move backwards.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) //move backward
            movetowardstarget(targetobject, true);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //move forward
            movetowardstarget(targetobject, false);
    }
    public void movetowardstarget(GameObject target, bool backwards)
    {
        float dir = backwards?-1.0f:1.0f;
        actualDist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position);
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) > minimumDistanceFromTarget) //we move only if we are further than the minimum distance
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, dir*movespeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else //otherwise, we stop moving
        {
            movingtowardstarget = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry i added thiswhole code instead of  public void movetowardstarget(GameObject target) its not working.should  change anyother thing?

Comment: sure. use below snippet for testing    
 `void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) //move backward
            movetowardstarget(targetobject, true);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //move forward
            movetowardstarget(targetobject, false);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way imo:
Add object for original position as well:

```
public GameObject targetobject, originalPosObj;
```

Then pass it as target:

```
movetowardstarget(movingtowardstarget ? targetObject : originalPosObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you will want to do this will the Mouse Wheel.

```
public class CameraConrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 centerPosition;//positon of object you want to zoom in and out of
    float MaxZoom = 3f;

    void Update()
    {
        //mouse wheel chaned
        if (Input.mouseScrollDelta.y !=0)
        {
            ZoomCamera();
        }
    }

    public void ZoomCamera()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(
            transform.position, centerPosition, Input.mouseScrollDelta.y);

        if(newPosition.y >= (centerPosition.y + MaxZoom ))
        {
            transform.position = newPosition;
        }        
    }
}
```